# iOS Swift UIImage resizing issue affecting performance; unexpected dimensions upon resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, image-resizing

I’m having a performance issue with images in a tableView (very jerky) and several view controllers (slow loading). In order to speed things up and smooth things out, I’m trying to resize the incoming images to the exact size of their respective `imageViews` upon initial loading instead of on the fly every time they are loaded from Core Data. The resized images will be stored as separate attributes on their parent Entity. All images are square, i.e., 1:1 aspect ratio.

**Here is the resizing code:**

```
extension UIImage {

    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        print("Inside resize function")
        print("targetSize is \(targetSize)")

        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is the function from which the resize function is called and to which it returns:**

```
    func difAndAssignPics() {

        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
// This is a copy of the original image, from which the smaller ones will be created

        print("bigToLittlePic size is \(bigToLittlePic?.size as Any)")

// These are the desired sizes of the three images I'm trying to create to facilitate performance

        let littlePicSize = CGSize(width: 110, height: 110)
        let mediumPicSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 160)
        let displayPicSize = CGSize(width: 340, height: 340)

// This is the call to the resize function for each target size

        littlePic = bigToLittlePic?.resize(targetSize: littlePicSize)
        mediumPic = bigToLittlePic?.resize(targetSize: mediumPicSize)
        displayPic = bigToLittlePic?.resize(targetSize: displayPicSize)

// This code differentiates between front view and rear view of the item and prints out the size of each

        switch switchTag {
        case 1:
            newCoin.obversePic = (displayPic)!.pngData()! as NSData
            newCoin.obversePicThumb = (littlePic)!.pngData()! as NSData
            newCoin.obversePicMedium = (mediumPic)!.pngData()! as NSData

            selectIndicatorLabel.text = "Now select Reverse photo"
            appDelegate.saveContext()

            print("Inside switch case 1, difAndAssignPics")

            if let imageData = newCoin.obversePicThumb{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("obversePicThumb size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }
            if let imageData = newCoin.obversePicMedium{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("obversePicMedium size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }
            if let imageData = newCoin.obversePic{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("obversePicBig size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }


        case 2:
            newCoin.reversePic = (displayPic)!.pngData()! as NSData
            newCoin.reversePicThumb = (littlePic)!.pngData()! as NSData
            newCoin.reversePicMedium = (mediumPic)!.pngData()! as NSData

            selectIndicatorLabel.text = "Now select Obverse photo"
            appDelegate.saveContext()

            print("Inside switch case 2, difAndAssignPics")

            if let imageData = newCoin.reversePicThumb{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("reversePicThumb size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }
            if let imageData = newCoin.reversePicMedium{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("reversePicMedium size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }
            if let imageData = newCoin.reversePic{
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("reversePicBig size is \(image?.size as Any)")
            }
        default: break
        }
        reactivateDataButtons()
    }
```

**Here’s what is being printed in the console at the introduction of each new image:**

```
bigToLittlePic size is Optional((2320.0, 2320.0))

Inside resize function
targetSize is (110.0, 110.0)
Inside resize function
targetSize is (160.0, 160.0)
Inside resize function
targetSize is (340.0, 340.0)
```

**Ok, so far so good. However, when the image gets back to `difAndAssignPics`, this is the printout:**

```
reversePicThumb size is Optional((330.0, 330.0))
reversePicMedium size is Optional((480.0, 480.0))
reversePicBig size is Optional((1020.0, 1020.0))
```

I included just the printout for the reverse images for brevity. Obverse gives identical numbers.

As you can see, somehow the size of each resized image has ballooned by a factor of 3. The pictures load, and the quality is high, but the performance is still noticeably suboptimal. I don’t know how to reconcile these numbers.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I printed out the size of the images that are being squeezed into the 110 x 110 imageViews in my custom cell. The numbers confirm that something in the resizing function is snafued. Here are the numbers in `cellForRow`:

```
obversePicThumb.size == Optional((330.0, 330.0))

reversePicThumb.size == Optional((330.0, 330.0))
```

**Edit #2**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045980/how-to-set-the-scale-when-using-uigraphicsimagerenderer) answered my question. Many thanks to those who took the time to look!

Comment: This is because of Retina Display. Three pixels map to a single point on the device. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045980/how-to-set-the-scale-when-using-uigraphicsimagerenderer

Comment: @Bill -- Yes sir, I did so, and it answered my question! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will make any difference, but here's my extension to accomplish this:

```
extension UIImage {
    public func resizeToBoundingSquare(_ boundingSquareSideLength : CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let imgScale = self.size.width > self.size.height ? boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.width : boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.height
        let newWidth = self.size.width * imgScale
        let newHeight = self.size.height * imgScale
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return resizedImage!
    }
}
```

My usage isn't with a `UITableView`, nor does it use `CoreData`. (I'd recommend doing things asynchronously for something like that.) But if your issue is with resizing, this should work with acceptable performance.

Comment: @dfd-- The loading speed is greatly enhanced. Unfortunately the quality of the images isn't very good, and I need the best res I can get for a pinch to zoom detail image. However, many thanks for your algorithm! I may be able to modify it to get a sharper picture. I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: Please see the link above for a solution to the scaling issue. It fixed my problem, might be helpful to you as well...